# How to fix error with aligned environment?

Tags: errors

I'm trying to make an aligned equation to produce a short proof answering a question about independence. However, when I compile this, I get a bunch of errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\?}{$ \overset{?}{=} $}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    %other class problems above
    \item[(d)]
    Can an event $ A $ be independent of itself?
    $ \ds
    \begin{aligned}
        P(A \cap A) & \? P(A)P(A) \\
        P(A) & \? P(A)^2
    \end{aligned} $
    If $ P(A) $ = 0 or 1, then the above equality is satisfied and A is independent of itself.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This is how I want it to look on the pdf though.
[image: image of what equation looks like]
I'm using aligned because it doesn't cause a vertical indent (unlike align*). I need to keep this problem in a tight space due to other problems on the page. How do I get rid of the errors?

Comment: Remove the `$` signs in the definition of the macro `\?`.

Comment: Yeah that fixed the compile errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem are the `$` inside the definition of `\?`. If you want to ensure that stuff only available in math-mode is available you should use `\ensuremath{}`:

```
\newcommand{\?}{\ensuremath{ \overset{?}{=}}}
```

Also you shouldn't set the `$ P(A) $ = 0 or 1`, because the spacing might be inconsistent. Instead use `$ P(A) = 0 \lor 1$` or `$ P(A) = 0 \text{ or } 1$`.

Comment: Yep, did this and got a clean compile. I'm not really sure why I put the $ signs there; I probably copy-pasted it from somewhere without thinking.